# How can I write text to an XML file?

Tags: php, xml

For some reason when I use fopen I get the following error:

**failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /examplefolder/examplefile.php**

And when I use this:

```
<?php
$myFile = "http://url.com/" . $_COOKIE['user'] . "/current_pro_pic.xml"; 
$xmlw = new XMLWriter; 
$xmlw->setIndent(true); 
$xmlw->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');  
$xmlw->startElement('user_current_pro_pic'); 
$xmlw->writeElement('full_url', "<![CDATA[sometexthere*]]>"); 
$xmlw->writeElement('time', date('l F jS Y ') . 'at' . date(' h:i A')); 
$xmlw->endElement(); 
$xmlw->endElement(); 
$xmlw->endElement(); 
$xmlw->endDocument(); 
?>
```

It spits out this:

```
Warning: XMLWriter::setIndent() [xmlwriter.setindent]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in *** on line 4

Warning: XMLWriter::startDocument() [xmlwriter.startdocument]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in *** on line 5

Warning: XMLWriter::startElement() [xmlwriter.startelement]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in ***p on line 6

Warning: XMLWriter::writeElement() [xmlwriter.writeelement]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in *** on line 7

Warning: XMLWriter::writeElement() [xmlwriter.writeelement]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in *** on line 8

Warning: XMLWriter::endElement() [xmlwriter.endelement]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in *** on line 9

Warning: XMLWriter::endElement() [xmlwriter.endelement]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in *** on line 10

Warning: XMLWriter::endElement() [xmlwriter.endelement]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in *** on line 11

Warning: XMLWriter::endDocument() [xmlwriter.enddocument]: Invalid or unitialized XMLWriter object in *** on line 12
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? It isn't the file permissions either fyi.

Comment: You  need to use a file path instead of a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard gets from a web page, are always read only. The server gets a question and sends you its answer. If you want to write XML to it you would need to post it, or, send it as a variable of get (the latter is space restricted)

Comment: Take a look at http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-data.php

As Pekka has suggested if the site is your own, you could do it to the local file direct, however, assuming as you're calling it via URL you may not have direct access.. post would be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a file by referring it using a http url. Even if the file is on same server, you have to give filesystem path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

you must call one of open* methods like [openMemory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-open-memory.php), [openUri](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-open-uri.php)

```
$xmlw = new XMLWriter; 
$xmlw->openUri('path_to_save');
// ... or
$xmlw->openMemory();
// ... youe code
$xmlw->setIndent(true); 
// ...
```